# SDL_Mixer functions Mix_Quit versus Mix_CloseAudio

Tags: c++, sdl2

Could someone please explain me the differences between the `SDL_Mixer` functions `Mix_Quit` and `Mix_CloseAudio`? I've read the documentation but couldn't really understand it clearly. When to use them and in which row (first `Mix_Quit` or `Mix_CloseAudio`?)?

Also, is it ok to use `Mix_Quit` after using `Mix_CloseAudio`? The documentation states that you should not call any `SDL_Mixer` function after `Mix_CloseAudio`, but it worked when I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

From the SDL 1.2 documentation (assuming that the functions in the API have not changed meaning):

> [`Mix_Quit`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_10.html) cleans up all dynamically loaded library handles,
>   freeing memory.
>
> [`Mix_CloseAudio`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_12.html) shutdown and cleanup the mixer API.
>   **After calling this all audio is stopped, the device is closed, and the SDL_mixer functions should not be used**.

Each `Mix_Init` call can load different dynamic library resources since it can have different flags

So, `Mix_Quit` must be called one time for each `Mix_Init` call and before `Mix_CloseAudio` (that must be called only once).

Comment: I just found that you need to call `Mix_Quit` even if you don't use `Mix_Init` yourself or end up with a memory leak as the soundfonts string would not be freed: https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL_mixer/blob/release-1.2.12/mixer.c#L230